# ExtJS how to make toolbar that wraps its elements?

Tags: javascript, extjs, toolbar

I have a toolbar with few filters, on a small screen (low res) some checkboxes are invisible (outside right edge). How to make toolbar (on a Grid Panel) that wraps its elements ?
I'm using extJs 3.4

Answer (score 5):

Off the top of my head you could use the `enableOverflow: true` config option in your `Ext.Toolbar` instance. This will add a button which, when clicked will show the items that could not fit in the toolbar originally.

Comment: That adds horizontal scrollbar, looks bad, but it solves the problem.
wait, no, it doesn't work on IE9, IE9 makes a lot of empty space below toolbar :/

Answer (score 0):

you can check out this extension too:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?12283-Scalable-(wrapping)-Toolbar-for-when-toolbar-needs-to-wrap